# How to disable F10 opening indicator-datetime?

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator, shortcut-keys

When I press F10, the indicator datetime opens up. How can I disable that? Another app use that as a keyboard short cut and I can't use it!

Using Ubuntu 11.04 Unity

I don't see F10 listed in my keyboard shortcuts too

Comment: F10 is supposed to open the applications menubar, though you can navigate to the indicators using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **gconf-editor**, press `Alt+F2` then type gconf... and Enter
While in **gconf-editor**, press `Ctrl+F` and type `F10` then tick on both radio-buttons. This should give you nice list at the bottom screen, where F10 "might" be assigned and an option to change it.

I also think that this shortcut is spammed. In my case I have it at:

- /desktop/gnome/interface/menubar_accel
- /apps/compizconfig-1/profiles/Default/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/panel_first_menu
- /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/panel_first_menu

And of course can't close `MC` right now, using only keyboard ;)